# Does there exist a homeomorphism under given sets?

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Let $X = \mathbb{R^2}-0$

and $Y = \{(x,y)|x^2 + y^2 =1\}$ , are these two sets homeomorphic ?

My answer is No.

If we assume there exist a continuous bijection $f : Y \to X$, then since $f$ is continuous,

$f(Y) = X$ must be compact because $Y$ is a compact set , here since $X$ is unbounded such a map cannot exist.

Hence, the sets are not  homeomorphic.

I have two questions at this point :

(i) Is my answer correct ?

(ii) Assuming my answer is correct, in the above proof do I also need to show that $Y$ is a compact set?

Comment: Yes, you are correct. And do you know the Heine-Borel theorem?

Comment: @HanulJeon: No, I am not aware of this theorem, can you tell me how is this related to this question ?

Comment: It states every closed bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is compact.

Comment: @HanulJeon: I see, Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is correct. Actually, you proved more than what you were supposed to prove: you proved that there is no continuous and surjective map from $Y$ onto $X$.

If you also need to prove or not that $Y$ is compact, that depends upon what you can assume. But, since $Y$ is a bounded and closed subset of $\Bbb R^2$, it is quite clear that it is compact.